# Topological classification of complex surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, 4-manifolds

The famous Enriques–Kodaira classification classfies the minimal complex surfaces by algebraic invariants, which give tight restrictions on the topology of the underlying manifolds. What about the opposite direction? In other words, **does there exist a classification of the homeomorphy types of topological $4$-manifolds which admit a complex stucture that makes them into minimal complex surfaces**? Some scattered results can be derived from the E-K classification directly: For example, $\Bbb{CP}^2$, $\Bbb{S}^2 \times \Bbb{S}^2$ and $\Bbb{CP}^2 \# \overline{\Bbb{CP}^2}$ are the only manifolds that can be given a structure of rational minimal surfaces, and $2\Bbb{E}_8 \# 3\Bbb{S}^2 \times \Bbb{S}^2$ is the only homeomorphy type of $K3$ surfaces. Therefore, I'm seeking for a generic solution (or information) of this question.

Comment: By minimal you mean containing no $-1$-curves? How then is $\Bbb CP^2\#\overline{\Bbb CP^2}$ on the list?

Comment: @TedShifrin There are minimal Hirzebruch surfaces homeomorphic to $\Bbb{CP}^2 \# \overline{\Bbb{CP}^2}$. You should just see $\Bbb{CP}^2 \# \overline{\Bbb{CP}^2}$ as a manifold, not as a blow-up process of $\Bbb{CP}^2$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. I haven't thought about these things in about 40 years.

Comment: You should clarify that you are interested in simply-connected surfaces. See also the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15847/classification-of-simply-connected-smooth-projective-varieties).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm not only interested in simply-connected case. I just refer to simply connected ones because I was not so familiar with the geometry of other surface types (like Kodaira surfaces).

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no such classification. I have two reasons for this belief:

1. We still don't know what complex surfaces belong to Class VII, namely, $b_1$ odd and Kodaira dimension $-\infty$. Examples of class VII surfaces include Hopf surfaces and Inoue surfaces. Every other known minimal examples are deformations of blowups of primary Hopf surfaces. It is conjectured that all minimal class VII surfaces are of one of the three aforementioned types. The missing ingredient is the existence of a [global spherical shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_class_VII#Classification_and_global_spherical_shells).
2. There are too many surfaces of general type, namely surfaces with Kodaira dimension $2$. There are many open questions about surfaces in this class, see [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602477) for example.

Having said that, the classification does yield a lot of topological information. In the context of your question, it is probably better to think of such information as a tool to rule out the existence of a complex surface of a given homeomorphism type.

Comment: Actually, I'm expecting some thing like "What conditions should the intersection form of a simply-connected $4$-manifold satisfy to admit a minimal complex structure" in the generic-type situation. Wikipedia gives some conditions on the Chern number but without the simply-connected assumption.

Comment: @Zerox: I don't know the answer and I assume it is open. There are some known restrictions though.